# How to transfer a value of a var from 1 func to another?

Tags: c#

I have 3 functions:

```
public int ok_join(string gr)
{

        ...................
        string gash = Regex.Match(response, @"gash:""(?<id>[^""]+)""").Groups["id"].Value;
        string groupId = Regex.Match(response, @"state:""smd=(?<id>[^""]+)""").Groups["id"].Value;
       ......................
}

public bool ok_post(string gr)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.site.ru/" + gash + "&stoud=" + groupId + "&");
    .........................
 }

public void go()
{
    while (true)
    {
        ........

                int h = ok_join(gr);
                if (h == 0)
                    ok_post(gr);
        .............
     }
}
```

How to send a value of gash and groupid from function ok_join to ok_post?­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Do you need to use gash in ok_post? But without passing it as parater, right?

Comment: i need to paste a value of gash and groupId(parsed in ok_join) to get request in ok_post

Comment: Please don't deface your question after you've posted it. Questions and answers are supposed to benefit future visitors, in addition to those asking and answering them.

Answer (score 4):

Go the full mile: have `ok_join` return a full blown object that contains your `int` return value (whatever `h` is supposed to represent, I'm guessing it's a pass/fail?), and `gash` and `groupId` then pass that into `ok_join`:

```
public class JoinResults
{
    public int h { get; private set; }
    public string gash { get; private set; }
    public string groupId { get; private set; }

    public JoinResults(int h, string gash, string groupId)
    {
        this.h = h;
        this.gash = gash;
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }
}
```

Then your methods/usage look like:

```
public JoinResults ok_join(string gr)
{
        string gash = Regex.Match(response, @"gash:""(?<id>[^""]+)""").Groups["id"].Value;
        string groupId = Regex.Match(response, @"state:""smd=(?<id>[^""]+)""").Groups["id"].Value;

        return new JoinResults(0, gash, groupId);
}

public bool ok_post(JoinResults joinResults, string gr)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.site.ru/" + joinResults.gash + "&stoud=" + joinResults.groupId + "&");
}

public void go()
{
    while (true)
    {
        JoinResults results = ok_join(gr);
        if (results.h == 0)
            ok_post(results, gr);
     }
}
```

Though I would strongly suggest you take a readability pass in terms of your member names, casing, etc, and whatever that `gr` variable is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2):

You could use out parameters

```
public int ok_join(string gr, out string gash, out string groupId) 
{
        ...................
        gash = Regex.Match(response, @"gash:""(?<id>[^""]+)""").Groups["id"].Value;
        groupId = Regex.Match(response, @"state:""smd=(?<id>[^""]+)""").Groups["id"].Value;
       ......................  
}

public bool ok_post(string gr, string gash, string groupId) 
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.site.ru/" + gash + "&stoud=" + groupId + "&");
    .........................  
}

public void go() 
{
    while (true)
    {
        ........
                string gash;
                string groupId

                int h = ok_join(gr, out gash, out groupId);
                if (h == 0)
                    ok_post(gr, gash, groupId);
        .............
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two real paths here:

1. These two variables represent "state" for the object that contains both methods.  It's rather hard for us to know if this is the case for you since we don't know what the object is, where exactly these variables are likely to be used, when they become obsolete, etc.  If these variables should exist for most, if not all, of the lifetime of the object they are in then they are most likely part of that object's "state".  If this true for you then you should create two private instance variables for the class containing both of these methods, set them both in `ok_join` and then read them in `ok_post`.
2. The two variables *do not* represent part of that object's state; you simply want to use the result of some function in another function called immediately after it; the data shouldn't persist beyond these two function calls.  In this case you want to return those two values from the first function, and the pass them into the next function.

For option #2 there are a few ways of actually implementing it in practice.  The big roadblock that you run into is that methods in C# (and most programming languages) can only `return` one value, not several.  One way to get around that is to use `out` parameters, as is demonstrated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13690837/1159478) other answer to your question by juharr.  Another option would be to create your own custom type, put everything that the function needs to return into that type, and then pass that type to the second function.  That could be implemented like so:

```
public class JoinResults
{
    public int H { get; set; }
    public string Gash { get; set; }
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can adapt your methods to look something like:

```
public JoinResults ok_join(string gr)
{
    string gash = "";
    string groupID = "";
    //...
    return new JoinResults()
    {
        H = 0,
        Gash = gash,
        GroupId = groupID,
    };
}

public bool ok_post(string gr, JoinResults joinResults)
{
    string url = "http://www.site.ru/" + joinResults.Gash + "&stoud="
        + joinResults.GroupId + "&";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    //.........................
    return true;
}
```

Then the calling code will look like:

```
JoinResults results = ok_join(gr);
if (results.H == 0)
    ok_post(gr, results);
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not delcare `gash` and `groupid` as globle variables ?

Comment: As data members would be better.

Comment: Right, but in his `ok_post` function, he tries to use `gash` and `groupid` directly.. so we can also declare it in `go` function, and use `out` keyword.

Comment: @user1872295 you can delcare it like `ok_post(string gr, string gash, string groupId)`, then invoke `ok_post` via `ok_join(gr, out gash, out groupId)`